# How to use asp.net WebApi Content Negotiator with asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, content-negotiation

I'm using asp.net MVC in combination with React.
My website composites from 2 parts, one for views that return React components, and another for doing works such as creating new object, logging in and out and etc.

I find out I can not using WebApi controllers along with MVC Controllers (WebApi Controllers will not detected in MVC website) but I need to use Content Negotiation in controllers, for example `Login` action returns `LoginResult` object and it must be serialized into json (according to Accept header of request, but result will be TypeName of `LoginResult`

How can I use WebApi's Content Negotiation in MVC Controllers?